# __PYTHON_EL_eval_file prints in interpreter when sending python file from buffer using C-x C-l

Tags: python, osx, elpy

Whenever I send the a Python buffer to the interpreter via `C-x C-l` it prints the file eval call as shown below. While it does print the correct output, it's a bit annoying to see it every time and I'd like help getting rid of that behavior.

My question is, How to get rid of the __PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/Users/user/Documents/Sandbox/Python/test.py", "", False) that prints in the interpreter when the file is sent with C-x C-l?

### Input

```
def main():
    print("Hello World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

```
>>> __PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/Users/user/Documents/Sandbox/Python/test.py", "", False)
Hello World!
```

I'm running on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68), using Emacs from EmacsforOSX.

Here's the output of running `M-x elpy-config`.

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 28.2
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python3 3.11.2 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/Users/user/.config/emacs/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python3 3.8.2 (/Users/user/.config/emacs/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.2
 Autopep8.........: 2.0.2
 Yapf.............: 0.32.0
 Black............: Not found (23.1.0 available)
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/flake8)

Warnings

You have not activated a virtual env. It is not mandatory but often a good idea
to work inside a virtual env. You can use `M-x pyvenv-activate` or `M-x
pyvenv-workon` to activate one.

The directory ~/.local/bin/ is not in your PATH. As there is no active
virtualenv, installing Python packages locally will place executables in that
directory, so Emacs won't find them. If you are missing some commands, do add
this directory to your PATH -- and then do `elpy-rpc-restart'.

Options

`Raised' text indicates buttons; type RET or click mouse-1 on a button to
invoke its action.  Invoke [+] to expand a group, and [-] to collapse an
expanded group.  Invoke the [Group], [Face], and [Option] buttons below to edit
that item in another window.

[+]-- Group Elpy
[+]-- Group Python
[+]-- Group Virtual Environments (Pyvenv)
[+]-- Group Completion (Company)
[+]-- Group Call Signatures (ElDoc)
[+]-- Group Inline Errors (Flymake)
[+]-- Group Code folding (hideshow)
[+]-- Group Snippets (YASnippet)
[+]-- Group Directory Grep (rgrep)
[+]-- Group Search as You Type (ido)
[+]-- Group Django extension
[+]-- Group Autodoc extension
```

And the Python-specific parts of my `init.el`

```
(elpy-enable)
(setq elpy-rpc-python-command "python3")
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
(setq python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters '("python3"))
```

Comment: What's the *question*?

Comment: How to get rid of the `__PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/Users/user/Documents/Sandbox/Python/test.py", "", False)` that prints in the interpreter when the file is sent with `C-x C-l`

Comment: Put that question in the question you posted somewhere, please. Q&A need to stand on their own; comments can be deleted any time, and they're not searchable. Thx.

Comment: Done. And thanks for prompting me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, but it worked for me:

```
(defun python-comint-filter (output)
  (let* ((regexp "^.*__PYTHON_EL_\\(.*\\)\\(.*\\)[[:space:]]*$")
         (lines (split-string output "\n"))
         (filtered-lines (remove-if (lambda (line)
                                      (or (string-match-p regexp line)
                                          (string-match-p "^\\s-*$" line))) 
                                    lines)))

    (if (equal (length lines) (length filtered-lines))
        output
      (mapconcat 'identity filtered-lines "\n"))))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions 'python-comint-filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. However, this problem only occurs with Python downloaded and installed from https://www.python.org

The issue can be fixed when I install Python with macports.
I installed Python like this, maybe it can help you.

```
sudo port install python311
sudo port install gnureadline

# if you need to use tkinter
sudo port install tk +quartz
sudo port install py311-tkinter
```

Comment: I unfortunately do not use macports. I did learn that this seems to be an issue with Elpy no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on Homebrew's Python 3.11. The solution was to install it via [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/), and set it to be the [global interpreter](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-global).You'll have to have pyenv's bin path recognized by Emacs (if you're on Doom you have to run `doom env`).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that’s what `python-shell-send-file` does. It sends code to be evaluated in the python repl that will cause the named file to be loaded and evaluated. The code that accomplishes this is bundled up into a pthon function called `__PYTHON_EL_eval_file`. This function’s name was chosen specifically so that it is unlikely to conflict with any functions that are part of the code you are writing.

You could use `python-shell-send-buffer` instead, if you want to paste the whole buffer contents into the repl.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying this is expected behavior? When I use `python-shell-send-buffer` it now prints `__PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/Users/user/Documents/Sandbox/Python/test.py", "/var/folders/62/pg1510rs0ml16dptw6mnnw4r0000gn/T/pyzj0KWS", True)` in the interpreter, along with parts of the buffer.

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: And by 'this' I mean it printing the function called __PYTHON_EL_eval_file(* instead of just executing it.

Comment: That seems strange. I remember using it before and it not printing the function call and just evaluating the file. Is this new behavior?

Comment: I haven’t used it in years, but it is my understanding that it always shows you the code it runs in the REPL. Surely it would be more confusing if it didn’t.

Comment: Just checked on a Windows machine and it only prints out the result of the evaluation. I now disagree that printing the function call and signature is expected behavior.

Comment: I am using Doom Emacs on Debian 11, when I send a file, I get only the output, no other extra info. What is your `python-shell-eval-file-setup-code`?

Comment: Actually, tried it with vanilla Emacs, also, I only get the output no extra info with `run-python` then `python-shell-send-file`. Emacs version 28.2.

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac OS X, and I remember that in the past I did not have this printing out every time I sent something to the shell - this is clearly not the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Arktik, it's a bit long to paste on a single comment. I'll spread it over two:

`Code used to evaluate files in inferior Python processes.
The coding cookie regexp is specified in PEP 263.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Value:
"def __PYTHON_EL_eval_file(filename, tempname, delete):
    import codecs, os, re
    pattern = r'^[  ^L]*#.*?coding[:=][  ]*([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)'`

Comment: `with codecs.open(tempname or filename, encoding='latin-1') as file:
        match = re.match(pattern, file.readline())
        match = match or re.match(pattern, file.readline())
        encoding = match.group(1) if match else 'utf-8'
    with codecs.open(tempname or filename, encoding=encoding) as file:
        source = file.read().encode(encoding)
    if delete and tempname:
        os.remove(tempname)
    return __PYTHON_EL_eval(source, filename)"
`

Answer (score -1):

This same issue arose for me when I installed `py-python-lsp-server` (and `python-lsp-server_select`) using MacPorts and didn't `select` both that and `python3.10` (also installed with MacPorts) using:

`sudo port select --set python python310`

`sudo port select --set python-lsp-server py310-pylsp`

I did this, ran `doom sync`, then restarted emacs, and the issue was gone.